# How to groupby and compute the probability in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows

```
id1, id2, thumb_up
 1,  1,   1
 1,  2,   -1
 1,  3,   1
 2, 1,   1
 2,  3,  -1
and so on
```

I want to create the following dataframe

```
id1, thumb_up_prob
 1, 0.66 ( 2 positive feedback and 1 negative = 2/3)
 2, 0.5 (1 positive and 1 negative feedback = 1/2)
```

and so on..
so basically i want to groupby id1 and compute the probability.
How do i do this in pandas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- check if `df.thumb_up` is equal to 1
- `groupby` `df.id1`
- since `bool` is subset of `int` we cal call `mean` on it

---

```
df.thumb_up.eq(1).groupby(df.id1).mean()
```

Answer (score 2):

With `apply` function and `lambda`

```
# df
df = pd.DataFrame({'id1':[1,1,1,2,2], 'id2':[1,1,3,1,3], 'thumb_up':
[1,-1,1,1,-1]})

# probability
df.groupby('id1').apply(lambda x: x[x>0].count()/len(x))
```

output:

```
 id1    id2 thumb_up
 id1            
 1  1.0 1.0 0.666667
 2  1.0 1.0 0.500000
```

Comment: How do I mention `thumb_up` column in the code above?